# Video documentary on the open source culture?

Tags: open-source, resources

I'm looking for some videos on these subjects:

1. A movie/documentary detailing the origin, history, and current state of open source culture
2. A movie/documentary on how open source software actually gets developed. What are the technical workflows. How do people create projects, recruit contributors, build a community, assign roles, track issues, assimilate new comers ... etc etc.

Could someone suggest a title?

Comment: I want a million dollars...

Comment: @FWFD: And a pony!

Comment: @Anon.: YES!!! PONEEeZ FTW!!!1!

Comment: ...And I want a solid gold house and a rocket-car.

Comment: lolz... folks you made me feeel trollish... I am changing the words... hope that cure you

Comment: @explorest: May I suggest: "Hello, I'm looking for some videos on these subjects. Might anyone be able to suggest a title?" And also lose the bold highlight, it sill looks very demanding (visually).

Comment: I believe that 2) will be a very boring documentary :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Revolution OS](http://www.revolution-os.com/)

> REVOLUTION OS tells the inside story
>   of the hackers who rebelled against
>   the proprietary software model and
>   Microsoft to create GNU/Linux and the
>   Open Source movement.

This covers number 1 pretty thoroughly, and has some tidbits of number 2.  Keep in mind that this is from 2001, so it's missing some of the more current history.  It's also available on Netflix Instant Streaming.

Comment: This movie certainly answers #1 (and probably #2 - i haven't seen it in a while), and I doubt there is any other movie like it.

Comment: It doesn't go into #2 very deeply, scratches the surface but that's all

Comment: This is perfect for No.1. But I have hard time looking for number 2

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that in more detail.  Updated my answer.